# Nagios: Enable HTML plugin output (urlize)?

Tags: nagios, icinga

The urlize output isn't showing up as a link within the Nagios cgi web interface. Is there an option that needs to be enabled for this to work?

Comment: Do you have `escape_html_tags = 0` in the cgi configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out and think it may come in handy for others. What I had to do was remove the <> characters from the "illegal" list within nagios.cfg. This is to be done on the server performing the active checks.